# What is the difference between javascript "window.onload" and just "onload"

Tags: javascript, onload

Could someone explain the difference between using `window.onload` and plain `onload` in javascript? I encountered both approaches, but am not sure if there is a difference. For example, to me, *as a complete beginner*, the following minimal examples appear to do the same thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {alert("this seems to work")}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>      
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            onload = function() {alert("this seems to work as well")}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Is `onload` just a shortcut, or is it something completely different?
Sorry for the inline javascript.

EDIT: My confusion arose from being a complete beginner, ignorant of, among many other things, the fact that, apparently, ["every property of the window object is a global variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041666/whats-the-purpose-of-referencing-the-window-object-in-javascript), and struggling specifically with `onload`. I would not treat these two questions as "exact duplicates," because one already needs to know part of the answer in order to understand that the two questions are related.

Comment: `onload` is a function in the global window scope. All window variables can omit the `window.` - like `alert("Hello")` is the same as `window.alert("Hello")`

Comment: unqualified variables are looked up in the scope hierarchy. If no variable matches, the global scope is the final place to identify the variable. Global variables are properties of the global object, which in browsers is `window`.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for this clear explanation. Might it be best practice to use the explicit variant instead of the implicit variant, to prevent just this kind of confusion?

Comment: I use it only in a few ambiguous situations such as `open`